# Update array key based on value change

Tags: php

Given I have an object

```
$obj = new StdClass();
$obj->name = 'my-object';
```

And that object is stored thusly

```
$store = [
    $obj->name => &$obj
];
```

Is there any way to change the store key when the property changes?

```
$obj->name = 'new-name';
// $store['new-name'] is not set, $store['my-object'] still is
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks Scott for pointing out I shouldn't store them this way. Here's what I came up with. There's probably some overhead here, but it's a core function.

```
$obj1 = new StdClass();
$obj1->name = 'my-object';

$obj2 = new StdClass();
$obj2->name = 'another-object';

$store = [
    $obj1, $obj2
];

$key = 'my-object';

$result = array_filter($store, function ($obj) use ($key) {
    return ($obj->name == $key);
});

// Results in: [$obj1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't store it by a value that could change. Use a unique identifier or guid.

If you can't do that (which you should) then make the name property private and use a `setName()` function. Within that function, find the object store, remove the old object, then change the name, then add the object back with the new name. Because the object now needs to know about the store, you will have more tightly coupled code (that's bad, but maybe necessary).

Comment: That would be ideal, yes, unfortunately, that's not how I can do it without massive overhead. It needs to be identifiable by a human, and the name they set, which they may need to change. What I'm trying to avoid is looping through the array to find the name each time someone 'asks' for it; There could end up being hundreds of objects.

Comment: I think I need something like array search to be able to do it like you suggest, but one that can look at properties of objects... Does a thing exist?

Comment: I added to my answer. You can probably just use `isset($store[$this->name])` can't you?

Comment: Scott, I think you were right initially to store them differently. I can use `array_filter` to do what I need.

Comment: I was right, yes. :)  But you shouldn't ever have to loop through the entire array. That's the point of having a key. Look up the object in the store while you still have a good key - then change the name afterwards.

Comment: Sadly the actual implementation is more complex, and adding another dependency of the store to each object is unachievable. Thanks for your help, it made me think at least.